# How to store ADC data in float buffer

Tags: floating-point, embedded, stm32

I want to read ADC data to float buffer in STM32L4 (with FPU)

I read ADC with DMA. When the buffer is full, then callback set flag and perform FFT calculations. To do this I need ADC data stored in a float buffer. Here is a problem, values of this are for example 1.51059974e-042. When I get value (adc_val = HAL_ADC_GetValue (&hadc1);) (uint32_t) data is good. Casting to float has the same result. When I calculate fft values are equal 0. I done some test with signal stored in vector and function for fft is proper, so problem is in ADC reading.

ADC.c

```
oid MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

  /** Common config
  */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_ASYNC_DIV2;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ADC_SCAN_DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  hadc1.Init.LowPowerAutoWait = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.Overrun = ADC_OVR_DATA_PRESERVED;
  hadc1.Init.OversamplingMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DFSDMConfig = ADC_DFSDM_MODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Regular Channel
  */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_8;
  sConfig.Rank = ADC_REGULAR_RANK_1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_247CYCLES_5;
  sConfig.SingleDiff = ADC_SINGLE_ENDED;
  sConfig.OffsetNumber = ADC_OFFSET_NONE;
  sConfig.Offset = 0;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

void HAL_ADC_MspInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};
  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 0 */

  /** Initializes the peripherals clock
  */
    PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_ADC;
    PeriphClkInit.AdcClockSelection = RCC_ADCCLKSOURCE_PLLSAI1;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Source = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1M = 1;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1N = 12;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1P = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1Q = RCC_PLLQ_DIV2;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1R = RCC_PLLR_DIV2;
    PeriphClkInit.PLLSAI1.PLLSAI1ClockOut = RCC_PLLSAI1_ADC1CLK;
    if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    /* ADC1 clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC_CLK_ENABLE();

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
    PA3     ------> ADC1_IN8
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_ANALOG_ADC_CONTROL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* ADC1 DMA Init */
    /* ADC1 Init */
    hdma_adc1.Instance = DMA1_Channel1;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_ADC1;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_adc1.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_WORD;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_adc1.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_adc1) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(adcHandle,DMA_Handle,hdma_adc1);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspInit 1 */
  }
}

void HAL_ADC_MspDeInit(ADC_HandleTypeDef* adcHandle)
{

  if(adcHandle->Instance==ADC1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_ADC_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**ADC1 GPIO Configuration
    PA3     ------> ADC1_IN8
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3);

    /* ADC1 DMA DeInit */
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(adcHandle->DMA_Handle);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END ADC1_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
}
```

Comment: And how do you know the problem is in ADC reading? Did you check it? Did you print/check with debugger that received ADC values are garbage even before you turn stuff into floats, back in the DMA buffer? Does ADC work as expected without DMA? The problem could be ADC reading, or it could be on the "convert to float" stage. You posted initialization, but none of the logic that would actually be interesting to see. You mention `adc_val = HAL_ADC_GetValue (&hadc1)`, but it's not anywhere in the code you posted. Please, fix this.

Comment: This is an X-Y problem.  You have decided erroneously that the issue is with the ADC, and asked about that and presented only that code.  You are wanting the ADC/DMA to do something it just physically cannot do.   The problem is in your signal processing, and you have not presented that code - merely vaguely mentioned casting the data - and there are many ways you could have got that wrong.

Comment: "_values of this are for example 1.51059974e-042._"  it is not clear what value you are referring to.  That is an extraordinarily small value - not from the ADC - not surprising you get zero out.  It sounds like you are casting the buffer type `(float*)` - that won't perform any kind of conversion, it will simply re-interpret the integer bit pattern as if it were a `float`, and the result will make no sense whatsoever.  You need to post your signal processing code and ask about that, because the ADC data is what it is, and it is not `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *so problem is in ADC reading*

The problem is not with the ADC - the ADC produces integer sample values, and the DMA just copies the ADC DR to successive memory locations.  It cannot do the conversion either.

The *problem* will be in how or where you performed the cast.  A safer solution would be on occurrence of the DMA transfer interrupt and convert the data to a float buffer in an iteration.

Bear in mind that simply casting an integer to a `float` will simply give you a `float` representation of the same magnitude.  So for example a value `2000` simply becomes `2000.0f`.  That may not be what your FFT expects.  Rather the input might be
require *normalisation* : 1.0 > s > -1.0 or 1.0 > s > 0 if not "signed".

For signed samples you would need to subtract the DC offset from the incoming signal, which may not be at the mid-point of the ADC range, and may in any case be variable or non-deterministic.  To deal with that you might need to apply a DC-blocking High-Pass filter (with a very low cut-off frequency).

In the end you cannot operate on the DMA buffer data directly in your FFT if your FFT expects float data.  Either transform the data to a form the FFT requires (a simple cast won't cut it) or use an integer FFT function.